# Query search string on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field thats defined as below.

```
"findings": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "orig": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
```

The findings contains the following text -

```
S91 - fiber cut
```

Now, when I do a 'term' search on 'findings.orig' for word 'fiber', I get a search response but when I do a a 'query string' search on 'findings.orig' for word 'fiber cut', I don't get any search response.

When I do a 'query string' search on '_all' for word 'fiber cut', I get the search response.

Why I dont get any response for 'fiber cut' on 'query string' search on 'findings.orig'.

Comment: Since you are searching on analysed version of findings field, you should get the result.I am getting the search result for above query. I am using 1.7.3. Are you sure you searched on findings.orig and not on findings.raw

Comment: Im searching on test.findings.orig, 'test' is my type..If I remove 'test' and just search in 'findings.orig' it works fine.

Comment: why are you doing test then. type name is not specified within the query_string clause

Comment: Im using the _head plugin "structured query" tab which automatically generates that query. Do you recommend any tool for generating queries?

Comment: also, thanks for all your responses.

Comment: I would recommend you to generate your query on your own.;)

Comment: ok, great..got it..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Elasticsearch: query_string nested search

You can try this, Hope it work...

```
GET index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "fields": ["findings.orig"],
        "query": "S91 - fiber cut"
       }
    }
}
```

If you want to search in nested fields use this.